# ArrayList resets itself

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an ArrayList of strings that I use to store image URLs.
Inside a for loop, I add a value to the ArrayList each time but after the for loop, the ArrayList seems to reset itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++) {
    imageFilePath = storageReference.child(imageUris.get(i).getLastPathSegment());

    StorageReference finalImageFilePath = imageFilePath;
    imageFilePath.putFile(imageUris.get(i)).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
        finalImageFilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {

            String imageUrl = uri.toString();
            imageUrls.add(imageUrl); // Here I'm adding to the ArrayList

            Log.d("test1", String.valueOf(imageUrls.size())); // the size is 1

        });
}


Log.d("test2", String.valueOf(imageUrls.size())); // the size is 0
```

EDIT:

I can't answer my own question so here is the solution (can see in comments):
the problem here is that I update the list in an `addOnSuccessListener`, since this function works on another thread, the code keeps running, therefor it prints the list in it's first form (before adding urls to it).

Comment: You add to `imageUrls` in a success listener; but the final `Log.d` line is executed immediately. You need to wait until everything is successful.

Comment: As @Andy Turner the success listener is executed on another thread or in a later update tick of the main looper (After your method is already done). So the list is empty when you call 'Log.d("test2", String.valueOf(imageUrls.size()));'

Comment: @IdoBarnea when the success listeners have all executed.

Comment: `imageUrls` ArrayList would be local in your code and so resulting in this.

Comment: It worked! thanks!

Comment: @IdoBarnea - I suggest you either post the solution as an answer or delete the question if you think not useful to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your imageUrls variable instance variable not a local variable. If it is a local variable then keep it outside the specific method.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you put this array as local so before oncrate put this code `ArrayList<String> imageUrls=new ArrayList<>();` now the variable is global
and if you want ArrayList is saved until the application is closed just make array static